# Different button, same navigation activity, but the result from fragment in navigation activity is different

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments, android-activity

i had a problem. I have many button with looping, and i want to intent them into same activity(navigation activity) but i want the result of fragment from navigation is different. Can you help me to solve this?

ButtonSelectActivity (the place of the button)

```
public class ButtonSelectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_button_select);

    LinearLayout f = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lala);
    f.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        for (int a = 0; a <= 7; a++) {
            for (int l = 65; l <= 90; l++) {
                Button button = new Button(this);
                button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                button.setText("" + (char) (l + (i * 4)));
                button.setId((char) (l + (i * 4)));
                row.addView(button);

                final String id = String.valueOf((char) (l + (i * 4)));
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(ButtonSelectActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        f.addView(row);
    }
}}
```

And this the activity result

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        if (position == 1) {
            return new FragmentDua();
        } else if (position == 0) {
            return new FragmentSatu();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return new FragmentTiga();
        } else
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Thankyou before :)

Comment: but i want the result of fragment from navigation is different? what do you mean by this?

Comment: the default of navigation activity have 3 fragment... so i want the result show in that fragment...

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you want different result depends on what button is clicked.*

Just pass your `final String id` in bundle to Main2Activity.class

So you should have in `ButtonSelectActivity` class

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ButtonSelectActivity .this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", id);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
```

And inside `onCreate` of `Main2Activity` class

```
int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("key");
```

Then you can show what you need depends on this `id` variable

UPD:

Also better practice is using `RecyclerView` where its elements contains `Buttons`. Would be the same but easier to work with.

Comment: i tried use recyclerview... but the result, application was force close

Comment: sorry, im a beginner from java
what you mean "Just pass your final String id in bundle to Main2Activity.class"?

Tahnkyou before, Sir :)

Comment: @AskaerIvan it means do what I exampled below, putExtra in one activity and get back with getInt in other Activity

Comment: the id is red underline btw... i dont know why... this so confused... But many thanks, Sir

Comment: @AskaerIvan and what IDE tells you?